# TI-Basic: Nspire Basic Function will show Too many arguments

Tags: texas-instruments, ti-basic, ti-nspire

I am currently struggling with TI-Basic. I am using a TI-Nspire CX II-T CAS and I want to write my own library and add some functions for statistics.

But at the moment I can not get to work any funcitons at all. Even the most basic code will not work.
What I did was:

1. Add a new Programm named "cube" type "Function" and Library Access "LibPub"
2. I have written the following Code

```
Define LibPub cube(n)=
Func

Return n^(3)
EndFunc
```

3. Saved it on my PC
4. Copied to Hanheld's MyLib
5. Refreshed the Handheld's library `Docs --> 6`
6. Open the Library and Call the Function that will look like `cube\cube(5)`

Then I get the Error Message: "Error: Too many arguments"

Does someone know where I made the mistake?

My Goal before was to do a function that will take `function(n,k)` and return the value of `n!/(n-k)!`. I mean both should be pretty straight forward. I hope someone could help me wasted already more then 6h on this...

Answer (score 2):

Found out what it was. The Code was not the problem. The problem is that CTRL+S will save the document but not the function. So if you want to Save it you have to first press CTRL+B and then move it.